# Angular to Excel

Tags: angular, angular6, xlsx, filesaver.js, sheetjs

I'm trying to export some JSON data from my Angular to Excel. I already did it successfully. My problem is how would i include the headings to the excel also?
I can only export the table but not the headings? Please see the link and codes below

[CLICK HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-export-xlsx-tgtmdw)

> CODE

```
public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {

    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    console.log('worksheet',worksheet);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    //const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
  }

  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
      type: EXCEL_TYPE
    });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
  }
```

> PIC

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following code once your have created your sheets

```
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(worksheet, [
    { A: '', B: '', C: ''},
], { header: ['A', 'B', 'C'], skipHeader: true, origin: -1 });
this.sheetHeaders(worksheet);
```

Updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-export-xlsx-salxs8?file=src/app/services/excel.service.ts)

Updated [stackblitz 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-export-xlsx-7npzsk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fexcel.service.ts)

Comment: It should create a row above the table headers. Yours is overriding the Eid, Ename, Esal @Siddhartha Gupta

Comment: Oops! Misinterpreted your question... Please look at update stackblitz

Comment: Thanks a lot but one more thing. I need to put value in headings like this for example  Name: 'Joseph', Age: 10, Gender: 'Male'. Thank you

Comment: can you paste a sample excel example

Comment: This seems to be a completely different task from initial question. Still I've added a new stackblitz for you. In future post a new question... Thanks